# Use of Generic Collection in Non-Generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics

I've spent quite a while today looking for a way to solve this but with no luck. I have a generic class as follows:

```
public class StagedEntity<T>: IStagedEntity where T : IStagedItem {

  public Type EntityType {
    get { return typeof( T ); }
  }

  public IList<T> StagedItems { get; set; }
}
```

in order that I can create a collection of StagedEntities of various arbitrary types, i.e:

```
var stagedEntities = new List<IStagedEntity> {
  new StagedEntity<StagedBrand> {
    StagedItems = new List<StagedBrand> {
      new StagedBrand {
        Code = "Brand1"
      },
      new StagedBrand {
        Code = "Brand2"
      }
    }
  },
  new StagedEntity<StagedModel> {
    StagedItems = new List<StagedModel> {
      new StagedModel {
        Name = "Model1"
      },
      new StagedBrand {
        Name = "Model2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then wish to iterate over each entity in `stagedEntities`, and with each one I need to be able to access all of the property values of each item in its `StagedItems` collection, something like:

```
private void DoStuff( IStagedEntity stagedEntity ) {

  var properties = stagedEntity.EntityType.GetProperties().ToList();

  foreach ( var item in stagedEntity.StagedItems ) {   <=== This line doesn't compile

    foreach ( var property in properties ) {
      // Do something with
      // property.GetValue( item, null );
    }
  }
}
```

However the above code doesn't compile because the interface definition `IStagedEntity` doesn't have `IList<T> StagedItems` defined, I can't put this in the interface definition because the interface is non-generic and so doesn't know what `T` is.

I've tried various things such as making the interface generic (`IStagedEntity<T>`) and defining `StagedEntities` as `new List<IStagedEntity<IStagedItem>>`, and I can get this to compile by casting each instance of `StagedEntity<T>` to `IStagedEntity<IStagedItem>`, however this fails at runtime with:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'DataExport.StagedEntity`1[DataExport.StagedBrand]' to type
'DataExport.IStagedEntity`1[DataExport.IStagedItem]'.
```

Is there an obvious way around this that I'm missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

---

EDIT: For completeness, the `IStagedEntity` interface at present looks like this:

```
public interface IStagedEntity {
  Type EntityType { get; }
}
```

Comment: How does the `IStagedEntity` interface look like?

Comment: Could you expose `IList<IStagedItem>` from the interface?

Comment: I might be missing something here but why are you using generics for this? Seems to me you can just declare StagedItems as List<IStagedItem>

Comment: @Glubus I want to constrain it so that when an instance of `StagedEntity<T>` is defined, it's `StagedItems` can only contain instances of that specific type `T`, not any other type that implements `IStagedItem`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Added interface definition.

Comment: @juharr Exposing `IList<IStagedItem>` from the interface just causes the compiler to complain that the `StagedEntity` doesn't implement it...

Comment: What does the `IStagedItem` interface look like? Usually, you should design your interfaces so that the consumer of the interfaces does not need to know the concrete type that it is using. I don't see this in the `IStagedEntity` interface. The `IStagedEntity` interface exposes only the `EntityType` property, which is not enough for the consumer. What do the implementors of `IStagedItem` have in common?

Comment: @CMillard Yes, you'd also have to implement it for it to work.

Comment: @juharr See my response to Glubus for why I've not done it like this.

Comment: @YacoubMassad The `IStagedItem` interface contains literally nothing. I've essentially used it just as a means of grouping it's implementors in order to reference them in the `where T : IStagedItem` constraint. I wonder now whether this should have been a base class instead. Each implementor basically has an arbitrary set of string properties which I need to access, nothing else.

Comment: Just trying to wrap my head around it; is this something you could recast and tackle with a Visitor pattern instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this to work by making the `IStagedEntity` interface generic so I can include `IList<T> StagedItems` in it - which I tried previously, but crucially I've now also made the interface type parameter covariant (`<out T>`) which has solved the conversion issue I was getting before:

```
public interface IStagedEntity<out T> where T : IStagedItem {
  Type EntityType { get; }

  IList<T> StagedItems { get; }
}
```

Obviously I've also had to amend all references to `IStagedEntity` to `IStagedEntity<IStagedItem>`, and having done so the assignment (simplified below) now works without issue:

```
var stagedEntities = new List<IStagedEntity<IStagedItem>> {
  new StagedEntity<StagedBrand>(),
  new StagedEntity<StagedModel>()
}
```

And with `IList<T> StagedItems` now in the interface I can happily access this property in my consuming method.

Thanks for your help everyone :o)

---

EDIT: It's possibly worth pointing out that adding the covariant `out` as described above will cause the compiler to complain of 'invalid variance' if there is a generic property with a setter on the interface. Simply removing the setter will fix this (and of course you can still have setters on the concrete implementation).

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the method signature of `DoStuff()`, I'd suggest to keep your interfaces and classes as they are and just change the argument like this:

```
private void DoStuff<T>(StagedEntity<T> stagedEntity) // note the arg type
{

  var properties = stagedEntity.EntityType.GetProperties().ToList();

  foreach ( var item in stagedEntity.StagedItems ) {
    foreach ( var property in properties ) {
      // Do something with
      // property.GetValue( item, null );
    }
  }
}
```

So you can call that method like:

```
private void foo()
{
    StagedEntity<MyGenericType> entities = null; // ...
    DoStuff(entities);
}
```

Comment: At the moment the calling method only has access to an object containing an `IList<IStagedEntity> StagedEntities` - I've also tried converting each of these to the appropriate `StagedEntity<T>` using it's `EntityType` property but not managed to get this to work either - not sure if that's a covariance/contravariance issue...

Comment: What about using a new interface `IHasStagedItems` as argument type?

Comment: I think that this would still require the new interface to be generic (`IHasStagedItems<T>`) as it would need to have `IList<T> StagedItems`, thus meaning that I have to use `<IHasStagedItems<IStagedItem>>` in the consuming method's signature and giving me the same conversion issues I had when I tried making the original interface generic.

Comment: If I get you right an interface providing the property `StagedItems` as `IEnumerable` could to the job I think. You won't need the `<T>` if you access the properties via reflection only.

Comment: But this wouldn't be type-safe - I want to constrain `StagedItems` to only be able to contain items of the parent `StagedEntity`'s type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic will get you the result that you are asking for. I would on the other side consider the other suggested approaches since you do not know if all IStagedEntity will meet the StagedItems property

```
private static void DoStuff(IStagedEntity stagedEntity)
{
        dynamic se = stagedEntity;
        var properties = stagedEntity.EntityType.GetProperties().ToList();

        foreach (var item in se.StagedItems)
        {   
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
             // Do something with
             // property.GetValue( item, null );
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - not ideal for the reason you point out (and generally compromising type-safety is arguably undesirable), but it's useful to be aware of it as an option.